# Conversion of datatypes - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, class, object, data-conversion

I'm confused about how I can implement conversion of different data types in my code below. Conversion includes (int to string, string to int, float to int, etc.) My teacher said this can be easily done when I am reading/writing files, but I'm still confused. I would appreciate any help or suggestions, thank you! Here's my code:

```
//files
var fs = require("fs");
//reading files
fs.readFile('sources.txt', (err, data) => {
  console.log("File output: " + data.toString());
  //writing files
      fs.writeFile('written.txt',data,(err, result) => {
        if(err) console.log('error', err);
      });
}); 

// planet class
class Planet{
    constructor(name, numberOfMoons, size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numberOfMoons = numberOfMoons;
        this.size = size;
    }
    orbit(){
        //return value
        return `${this.name} is a planet and therefore orbits around the sun.`
    }
}

//inheritance class
class DwarfPlanet extends Planet{
    constructor(name, numberOfMoons, size, orbitalNeighbourhood) {
        super(name, numberOfMoons, size);
        this.orbital = orbitalNeighbourhood;
    }

    getOrbital(){
        //return value
        return `${this.name} is a dwarf planet because it doesn't have a clear orbital neighnourhood "`
    }

}

let earth = new Planet('Earth', 1 , 6371);
console.log(earth.orbit());

let pluto = new DwarfPlanet("Pluto", 5 , 1188, 'Kuiper Belt');
console.log(pluto.getOrbital());

//Array of Objects (anonymous option)
var stars = [
    {
        name: 'Sun',
        temperature: 5778,
        colour: 'White'
    },
    {
        name: 'Pistol',
        temperature: 11800,
        colour: 'Blue'
    },
    {
        name: "Antares",
        temperature: 3500,
        colour: "Red"
    }
];

// Array of Objects (using Planet Class)

var planets = [
  new Planet('Earth', 'One moon', '6,371 km'),
  new Planet('Mars', 'Two mooons', '3,389 km'),
  new Planet('Uranus', 'Twenty-seven moons', '25,362 km'),
  new Planet('Saturn', 'Fifty-three moons', '58,232 km'),
];


console.log("Fun Fact: the biggest star isn't the sun, instead it is a blue star called 'Pistol'. Here's some information about it: ");
console.log(stars[1]);

console.log('Here are some planets and their properties:');
console.log(planets);
```

Comment: STart here: [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: I've never really learnt JSON, but I'll check it out I'm more just confused about how I can convert data like in my code what could I add that would involve data conversion? @RandyCasburn

Comment: The answer is in the page I linked. You didn't even look at the content in the link. Can't help you if you don't help yourself.

Comment: Does your teacher give you the source file, or you need to create it for yourself?

Comment: I did check the link, but I didn't really understand it

Comment: @RoboRobok I need to create it myself

Comment: Well, yeah - then JSON is the best and simplest idea. The docs suggested by Randy are confusing indeed. This one is a bit lengthy, but more straightforward: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Thank you for the link! I just read through it and correct me if I'm wrong but would I just take my planets array and stringify it? @RoboRobok

Comment: Yes, exactly. And you can store that JSON in a file, for example `planets.json`. Storing data in JSON files is extremely common for web these days. Then, you could read that file and convert this back to your planets objects.

Comment: @RoboRobok - Your link clearly had a better impact. I'll use it with beginners in the future - lesson learned!

Comment: Ok, thank you! And to make a JSON file would I just code out planets.json? Also, could you make just clarify the last part a bit because I didn't quite get how to do that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn no worries, it's just that docs for `JSON.stringify()` are a bit confusing, especially the `replacer`, which is not needed in 99.9999% of cases.

Comment: sorry I forgot to tag you @RoboRobok

Comment: @28spaceaddict you will get your JSON all ready with simple `JSON.stringify(planets)`. If you want your JSON more readable, give it some indentation with for example `JSON.stringify(planets, null, 4)` (4 spaces as an indentation). Remember that JSON is just a text! Then, when you read a file, you will get the array with `JSON.parse(fileContents)`, where `fileContents` is just a text value from your file (which means your JSON!). After that you can loop that array (or `map()` it) to convert it to the actual planets instances.

Comment: @RoboRobok oh ok so just by writing out JSON.parse(fileContents) a file will be created for me or do I have to create my own readable file? and how would I be able to loop the array to convert it to the actual planet instances? Sorry if I'm asking too many questions!

Comment: JSON has nothing to do with the file, we didn't get to the file. What `JSON.parse(something)` does is just returning the little something represented by JSON format. It can be a string, number, array, object or boolean or null. Remember, once again, that JSON is just a string. But with `JSON.parse(something)` you can convert that string to something, if only it makes for a valid JSON :) Try `console.log(JSON.parse('[1, 2, {"a": 3}, false]'))`.

Comment: @RoboRobok oh ok! What if I wanted to read from a file while doing a data conversion how would I be able to do that using JSON?

Comment: You don't "read while doing a conversion". You just read the file like you already do and then pass the contents of your file to `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: I gotta go to bed now, pls leave the questions if you have some. But try yourself first, it's fun :D Good luck.

Comment: @RoboRobok idk if your asleep, but it works fine except the json.parse, I'm still very confused about how to implement that within my program so it all relates to each other

Comment: @28spaceaddict did my answer below help? :)

Comment: @RoboRobok yes it did thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to read and write files is to use their synchronous counterparts: `readFileSync()` and `writeFileSync()`. In order to work with JSON neatly, you can define your functions as:

```js
const filePath = 'planets.json';

function readPlanets() {
    const json = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    const planets = JSON.parse(json);

    return planets.map(planet => new Planet(
        planet.name,
        planet.numberOfMoons,
        planet.size
    ));
}

function writePlanets(planets) {
    const json = JSON.stringify(planets, null, 4);

    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, json);
}
```

Then, you can populate your `planets.json` file:

```js
const planets = [
    new Planet('Earth', 1, 6371),
    new Planet('Mars', 2, 3389),
    new Planet('Uranus', 27, 25362),
    new Planet('Saturn', 53, 58232),
];

writePlanets(planets);
```

To read it back, you use the `readPlanets()` function:

```js
const storedPlanets = readPlanets();
```

Notice how I manually `map()` data to `Planet` instances in `readPlanets()`. JSON itself has no idea of the class - the objects created by `JSON.parse()` are basic JavaScript objects.

Also notice how I changed the format of your data a bit. Instead of using values like `'Twenty-seven moons'` or `'6,371 km'`, I just put a simple number in JSON: `27` and `6371`. That's because you usually want to keep your data as raw as possible, because display format is something that you could want to change anytime. The data should persist. If you want to translate these raw numbers to your format, I'd suggest adding methods to your `Planet` class to return the formatted numbers of the moons and the sizes.